# Xlsxwriter: Grouping using set_column after setting width with set_column

Tags: xlsxwriter

I'm using xlsxwriter to write data and afterwards autofit the columns to the maximum string length of every column.

For that I'm using something like for every single column (as every column has different max string lengths):

```
    Sheet1.set_column(0, 0, 15)
```

At the end of my script I want to group a few columns together. Hence using something like this from the doc:

```
  Sheet1.set_column(0, 10, None, None, {'level': 1})
```

The grouping shows but not for the desired columns. Am I doing something wrong? Interestingly, the formatting (i.e. the column width) of one of the grouped columns went away, somehow seems to get overwritten. Also I tried something like set_column('A:D', None, None, {'level': 1}) but doesn't work either.

When grouping an empty sheet, ie without writing any data, hence without applying any styles, it works. Isn't it possible to use consecutive set_columns on the same columns??

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't it possible to use consecutive `set_column()` on the same columns??

No. Any call to `set_column()` will overwrite previous calls in the same range.

So you will need to group together all the options that you want to set, such as width, format or grouping, and apply them in one go.

Also, you will need to set overlapping ranges separately. Like this:

```
# Not like this!
worksheet.set_column(0, 9, 20, None, {'level': 1})
worksheet.set_column(4, 5, 30, None, {'level': 1})

# Use separate non-overlapping ranges.
worksheet.set_column(0, 3, 20, None, {'level': 1})
worksheet.set_column(4, 5, 30, None, {'level': 1})
worksheet.set_column(6, 9, 20, None, {'level': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, nice that you're giving some sort of support here on SO. I saw an extension on GitHub which stores all the formats of every cell and extends it wherever you do consecutive calls. I just forgot the name of the GitHub but you probably know it... I'll see whether that'll work.

Comment: But apart from that: how should I go and group columns which have different widths for example? E.g. doing set_col('A:C', None, None, {'level':1}) but still apply different widths to columns A, B, C? Dunno how to do it!?!?! Thanks

Comment: @tim I've updated the example to show how to set the width and options at the same time.

Comment: thanks, but what I will don't get. When calling a few times set_column on columns side by side they'll get connected into one group. Good, than I can use it and apply different widths to every single column. But how to make distinguished groups? Simply changing level doesn't seem to work. E.g. I'd like to have a group from column 1 to 5 with 5 different widths and than a second distinguish group from column 6 to 10 with also 5 different widths again. Thanks once more

Comment: Sorry for pushing for this feature, but maybe you have missed my comment as I didn't use your name in it!? Is it possible to make unconnected groups like mentioned in my previous comment? Thanks

Comment: @tim *> I'd like to have a group from column 1 to 5 with 5 different widths and than a second distinguish group from column 6 to 10 with also 5 different widths again* I don't think that is possible in Excel. You need to leave at least one ungrouped column between groups or else all contiguous columns at the same level are grouped together.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that but you are absolutely right! Thanks again, than I know my job from here onwards :)